# Sound recorder for Mac OS X

Tags: macbook-pro, software-recommendation, audio

I'm looking to record lectures with my MacBook Pro this year. Is there any good, free software that is capable of producing recordings from a potential distance?

Comment: If you worry about the distance you need a good microphone, software won't help you there.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want a simple way to record audio, you can use the QuickTime Player application. Just choose File > New Audio Recording, and hit record.

As was mentioned already, the quality of your recording is going to be highly dependent on your microphone. The internal one is likely to pick up a lot of extra noise -- but you never know until you try. If you do get an external microphone, QuickTime Player also lets you record from other input sources (use the pulldown menu on the right side).

Answer (score 0):

you can use any audio recording software, for example [AudaCity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/?lang=en) I don't know the recording quality of MacBook Pro but you could buy a small directional microphone and record lectures from a distance.

Comment: I can not recommend Audacity for recordings longer than 30 minutes (or basically anything at all, but that is my personal opinion). It's just not stable enough on OS X. The already mentioned QuickTime Player X will work well for that. As already suggested, recording quality heavily depends on the microphone, not the software.

Comment: @MacLemon Have you had that happen with Audacity recently? I've done recordings that lasted a very long time (over 2 hours) and I haven't had a problem. It was a bit slow to save, but that's to be expected.

Comment: Yes, also with recent/current versions of Audacity. You just do not want to take any risk. Especially when it comes to things like 12h recordings. Audacity is free and a nice tool for small things. It is not stable enough for (professional) longer recordings. YMWV